# Android app, Error when try to send email

Tags: java, android, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I downloaded the example: 
     https://dev.office.com/Getting-Started/office365Apis?platform=option-android#register-app
clicking on send button throws this error:

```
RetrofitError: 404 Not Found
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Bearer access token is empty.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "951626d4-0168-4b58-a78a-1fdd3bd322f2",
      "date": "2016-04-29T18:34:05"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume you don't like that error and expected something else. The reason for the error is "Bearer access token is empty." Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like perhaps you did not register your app before downloading the sample.  The readme instruction in the sample should walk you through registering and configuring an app, at which point the login should succeed and you will get a bearer token.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing an access token. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/discovery-service-rest-operations:

> Discovery Service operations
>
> Initial sign in
>
> This brings the client to a web page where the user enters account information. It returns the endpoints needed to continue with Discovery Service. This is used the first time a user tries your application. It tells your application:
> what cloud the user belongs to
> where the app can send the user to log in
> where to go to get a token

you can continue reading it on the official site.

Comment: The sample the OP is asking about is a Microsoft Graph one.  Microsoft Graph apps do not use the Discovery Service, but rather get tokens directly from AAD.